# Send push notifications on ios from Amazon SNS to APNS

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am trying to receive a payload (from push notifications) from AWS SNS using firebase (all done in flutter). I can successfully receive a push notification from SNS using type 'notification' messages but when changing this to type 'data' I do not receive anything. I need to receive type 'data' to produce a notification on the app side (depending on what message is included in the payload). Is there a way I could do this using type 'data' or is there a way to disable automatic notifications being sent to my phone when using type 'notification'. If there is any other way to do this, I'll be happy to try them out.